# Scala and the Java Memory Model

Tags: scala, concurrency, final, java-memory-model

The Java Memory Model (since 1.5) treats `final` fields differently to non-`final` fields. In particular, provided the `this` reference doesn't escape during construction, writes to `final` fields in the constructor are guaranteed to be visible on other threads even if the object is made available to the other thread via a data race. (Writes to non-`final` fields aren't guaranteed to be visible, so if you improperly publish them, another thread could see them in a partially constructed state.)

Is there any documentation on how/if the Scala compiler creates `final` (rather than non-`final`) backing fields for classes?  I've looked through the language specification and searched the web but can't find any definitive answers.  (In comparison the `@scala.volatile` annotation *is* documented to mark a field as `volatile`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dug through the history to find out when the change was made.

- [Bug Report](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/201) October 2007
- [Commit](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/13495) November 2007

The projection of Scala into the JVM isn't covered by the language specification.

Comment: But the behaviour, from a concurrency perspective, of language constructs should be part of its specification I would argue!

Answer (score 3):

It creates a `final` field when you declare something as a `val`. Anything whose references can be modified, such as a `var`, can (obviously) not be `final` underneath.

This means that `case classes` contain final fields also (as the arguments to a case class constructor are implicitly `val`s)

Comment: I don't think this used to be the case (see http://old.nabble.com/Val-and-Final-td13355515.html for example).  Part of the reason for my question - if this can change without any documentation, how do I know it won't change again?

Comment: You are correct that this should have been documented. This is not merely an issue of performance but part of the language itself due to the memory model. I was not aware that vals used to be non-final

Answer (score 2):

I've filed a documentation bug for this in the [Scala bug](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/3226) system.